# Fixing a windows problem using Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I do not know is it okay to ask this kind of question here or not,
so if is not okay, forgive me please!

I have dual boot pc with ubuntu and windows 10. Recently I installed an old program on windows that caused "Automatic Repair" problem. I have tried the cmd method and troubleShoot but they didn't seem to work. As some sites and videos say, now the solution is to use a bootable USB and restore some files that are missing.

Before I try that way, I wondering is it a simpler way to fix this because I have access to all windows files through ubuntu?

ps: I deleted that bad file from where I have installed it. (program files)

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to find out which files are missing?

Comment: Ubuntu has no tool to tell you what files are missing (or damaged) from a Windows install. You need a Windows install/repair disk for that. If you already (somehow) knew which files, and already (somehow) had a copy of those files, then you could use Ubuntu to access the Windows partition and copy the files over.

Comment: In windows, you could use your system restore points to restore a previously working configuration. If you did not setup a restore point, then you should re-install windows as all those repair programs in windows are basically worthless.